# How to position image on top left corner?

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to position an overlayed image in the top left corner of my chart.

To that end, I am using the `aggregate` transform directly in the encoding of channels x, and y of the image, as it can be seen [in this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAjJQAMlAFYQ2AOxAAaEAHcaAE3poQUFZiQ1lcAE7qQOpCbSgGFwQdsnOOMTLlQIxEAC+GpgWSMoQAGZsFghoANqgmDQIcACqynQGDJhQAJ5wSDHGMNYRNHCCOq52cNZIEAYIxQ0BALoagkj5VqgJIHDKRjpmZA4gAB5jZRVV6E3K9A3BuTi16JiIONFILsF0gmvKDIKCQSC5U+WVBjgWNFC1y6sGAI4MYUkmSaTWnwcGAAU7g9AmdOt14qBkBYANZjTArNYgQoFaxGQTRAwAYgAzAAOADsOKYAE5SjQTgB5HBIKB0C6oOQE4JsNiCJI4NAhBhwAJBKGFOGoRKIgzCcxotmY9BYgAseLxOKgZL5agFsPhovQySQZEeWl0+lQXg0OxoZFU6AOEUwgQ0AyGIzGk2FyLIZAsfA2jTM5JmjWavy1IA2CC2oRcZwZoF1Hq9SOQkw002u6Fu931COe6DeHzodhoPzOThcruIOx51XcESi40oOGUoz5bRbQA).

Here is the specific code snippet of the image mark:

```
   {
        "mark": {"type":"image", "width":50, "align":"left"},
        "encoding": {
            "x": {"aggregate": "min", "field":"months", "type":"temporal"},
            "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field":"price", "type":"quantitative"},
            "url": {"value": "data/ffox.png"}
        }
    }
```

The image, is still appearing at around the middle of the y axis, and not at the top:

[Image in the middle, not top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAb9V.png)

How can I place it at the top left corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not getting displayed in top because height is not provided for that `image` mark. Because of that image is getting displayed in center, if you inspect your image you will see some default height. [Image for default height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpoV4.png)

To bring your image on top left, just provide `height` as done below:

```
{
      "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 50, "align": "left", "height": 40},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "months", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
        "url": {"value": "data/ffox.png"}
      }
 }
```

But with the aggregation specified, your image might slighly go outside the chart view, so you can provide the following way as well where you provide hardcoded `x` and `y` value for the image mark. Which will always show appropriate position for your image. Below is the code and editor [url](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.1.0.json",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "transform": [{"timeUnit": "utcyearmonth", "field": "date", "as": "months"}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "months", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Price"}
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "area",
            "color": "#3873b9",
            "fillOpacity": 0.7,
            "tooltip": true
          }
        },
        {"mark": {"type": "line", "color": "#4883c9"}}
      ]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 50, "height": 40, "align": "left"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 0,
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "axis": null
        },
        "y": {
          "datum": 0.8,
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "axis": null
        },
        "url": {"value": "data/ffox.png"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {
    "axis": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"},
    "scale": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [wahab memon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7734100/wahab-memon) mentioned, the image went middle due to the missing of `height` property.

Simply adding back `"height": 50, "baseline": "alphabetic"` to `mark` can fix the position and the overshoot issue as well. **(no need for hard coding)**

Last but not least, the original code has redundant nested layers, please see the complete code below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.1.0.json",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {"url": "data/sp500.csv"},
  "transform": [{"timeUnit": "utcyearmonth", "field": "date", "as": "months"}],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "months", "type": "temporal", "title": null},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Price"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "area",
        "color": "#3873b9",
        "fillOpacity": 0.7,
        "tooltip": true
      }
    },
    {"mark": {"type": "line", "color": "#4883c9"}},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 50, "align": "left", "height": 50, "baseline": "alphabetic"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "months", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
        "url": {"value": "data/ffox.png"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-NoBIA)